# Google Image Chart: pie charts all sides same size

Tags: image, charts

I use Google Image Charts (deprecated library) to put some graphs in a PDF that I create on my website. I don't know why, but for some reason this pie chart:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p&chs=500x250&chco=FFFF10,FF0000&chd=t:1560,2550,3750,4680,5140,5580,5510,4750,3530,2270,1410,1240&chl=January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December
```

Creates 12 identical looking sides in the chart. While this one:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p&chs=500x250&chco=FFFF10,FF0000&chd=t:12,3,4,5,6,7,8,5,3,2,6&chl=January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December
```

creates it properly. They are identical other than different data. Does anyone know the cause of this? Thanks a lot

Comment: What to you think to post a part of your code?

Comment: this IS the code, that's how google image graphs work, they're just URLs